# Help opening USB serial link

Tags: debian, usb, serial-port

My goal is to talk to an ARM mmc through a Segger serial link using this command:

```
python3 -m serial.tools.miniterm -e /dev/ttyUSB3 115200
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB3'
```

If I use dmesg, I can see the Segger serial device connected to a usb port (see below):

```
[159707.574338] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[159707.724537] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1366, idProduct=0101, bcdDevice= 1.00
[159707.724542] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[159707.724545] usb 1-3: Product: J-Link
[159707.724546] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SEGGER
[159707.724548] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 000801025943
```

So it looks to me like I am connected to USB3 but that I can't open up a serial link. Also see this:

```
USER@USERdev:/dev$ ls -ld ttyU*
ls: cannot access 'ttyU*': No such file or directory
```

Any idea as to why I can't open up a serial link?
I am running Debian 11.7

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: There's no serial port offered by the Segger device, as far as we can tell from your logs

Comment: The J-Link Segger device does offer a serial link. Any thoughts as to what would be preventing me from seeing it?

Comment: as said, as far as we can tell from your output, it *doesn't*; it's not that you can't see it, it's just not existing, unless you cut something like "new serial port tty…" from your dmesg logs (which I doubt you did!)

Comment: Mistyped command, do: `ls -ld /dev/ttyU*`.

Comment: @waltinator OP is already in `/dev`, so that's not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/ttyUSB3"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: Well, there's no ttyU* anywhere in /dev, according to OP, so sadly that doesn't address the issue. Also, it's not how you *should* do this: appropriate would be using a udev rule to automatically (and every time) change ownership and permissions, instead of adding an unprivileged user to a group they should potentially not be in.

Comment: I journalctl --follow and I have these results:   : checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"     and then        <pre>bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device</pre>

Comment: If I do the ls -l  before and after diff I see no changes.

Comment: Would it be possible that my device is showing up in some sub directory of  '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3'     ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a feature of J-Link SEGGER that the [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1833323.pdf) calls "Virtual COM port" (chapter 5.14 in datasheet).

However, that feature may need to be first switched on, using either "J-Link Commander" or "J-Link Configurator". Both of these appear to be Windows applications.

`/dev/ttyUSB*` device nodes in Linux are associated with USB-to-RS232 (or RS485) adapters. In Windows, RS232 or RS485 ports are known as COM ports.

But a J-Link SEGGER (a JTAG debugger) promises a data transfer rate that is an order of magnitude higher than is typical for classic RS232-style serial ports, so I think the "virtual COM port mode" is *not* the device's primary communication mode over USB. Instead, it probably uses native USB protocols for higher data rates, and the comparatively slow virtual COM port emulation needs to be activated as a secondary function, if required.

If you don't have a Linux version of J-Link configuration software available to you, you may have to temporarily connect your J-Link device to a Windows system with appropriate software, use it to change the device's settings to enable the "Virtual COM port" and save the new settings to the device, and then move the reconfigured device back to your Linux system and try again.